# Apache does not load php files

Tags: server, apache2, php

Everything working fine until I upgraded php version to php5.6. I have installed php5.6 using composer. when I restart apache2 server and start it again, server stopped loading php files.help please, `httpd.conf` file is empty. My current apache2 version is `Apache/2.2.22(Ubuntu)` And `mods-enabled` folder contains below files.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Jun 27 22:25 alias.conf -> ../mods-available/alias.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Jun 27 22:25 alias.load -> ../mods-available/alias.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Jun 27 22:25 auth_basic.load -> ../mods-available/auth_basic.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Jun 27 22:25 authn_file.load -> ../mods-available/authn_file.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Jun 27 22:25 authz_default.load -> ../mods-available/authz_default.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Jun 27 22:25 authz_groupfile.load -> ../mods-available/authz_groupfile.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Jun 27 22:25 authz_host.load -> ../mods-available/authz_host.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Jun 27 22:25 authz_user.load -> ../mods-available/authz_user.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Jun 27 22:25 autoindex.conf -> ../mods-available/autoindex.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Jun 27 22:25 autoindex.load -> ../mods-available/autoindex.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Jun 27 22:25 cgid.conf -> ../mods-available/cgid.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Jun 27 22:25 cgid.load -> ../mods-available/cgid.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Jun 27 22:25 deflate.conf -> ../mods-available/deflate.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Jun 27 22:25 deflate.load -> ../mods-available/deflate.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Jun 27 22:25 dir.conf -> ../mods-available/dir.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Jun 27 22:25 dir.load -> ../mods-available/dir.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Jun 27 22:25 env.load -> ../mods-available/env.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Jun 27 22:25 mime.conf -> ../mods-available/mime.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Jun 27 22:25 mime.load -> ../mods-available/mime.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Jun 27 22:25 negotiation.conf -> ../mods-available/negotiation.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Jun 27 22:25 negotiation.load -> ../mods-available/negotiation.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Jun 27 22:25 reqtimeout.conf -> ../mods-available/reqtimeout.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Jun 27 22:25 reqtimeout.load -> ../mods-available/reqtimeout.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jun 27 22:25 setenvif.conf -> ../mods-available/setenvif.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Jun 27 22:25 setenvif.load -> ../mods-available/setenvif.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jun 27 22:25 status.conf -> ../mods-available/status.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jun 27 22:25 status.load -> ../mods-available/status.load
```

Comment: At least this should contain a link called `php5.6.conf` to `../mods-available/php5.6.conf`, and similarly for `php5.6.load`.

Comment: How to load that file into mods-available folder?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Apache module for PHP is missing. Install the service using;

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```